# show transparent loader on page transition - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Am trying to add Circle loader before the user rout to another page, i have installed the `flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0` package and imported it, i have used it on my navigation bar as follows:

```
 onTap: () {
                //Close the Navigation window
                Navigator.pop(context);

                //Loader Implementation
                Center(
                    child: SpinKitCircle(
                        color: Colors.purple,
                        size: 50.0,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000)));

                //Rout to next page
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const MyChallenges()));
              },
```

the loader is not showing (ignored), am trying to show the loader on the page of context for like two seconds then user will be redirected to the other page, any ideas please. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do the trick neatly, `showDialog()` would display the spinkit and with `barrierDismissible: false` property and `WillPopScope()` would prevent the user from popping the loader.

```
   Navigator.pop(context);

   showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
         return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
               return false;
            },
            child:const SpinKitCircle(
               color: Colors.purple,
               size: 50.0,
            ),
         );
      },
   );

   await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds:2), (){
      Navigator.pop(context);
   });

   Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => const MyChallenges(),
      ),
   );
```

Also if you prefer to have a transparent background just set the `barrierColor` property of the `showDialog()` to either null or Colors.transparent.

Comment: Thank you for answer but the loader is stuck, any idea ?

Comment: @editix the loader remains after it successfully navigates to the MyChallenges() page?

Comment: @ShinaMyth it actually doesn't navigates to MyChallenges() page it opens the loader and just keeps loading

Comment: i will consider your answer as showing the loader, but i have posted another question on why it is stuck. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return const Dialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );

 await ...

 Navigator.pop(context);

  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (ctx) => YoutubeSubtitleScreen(
        videoId: loadVideoId,
        userWord: userWord,
      ),
    ),
  );
```